# Comparing 2 non-linear curves

Tags: geometry, polynomials, algebraic-curves, nonlinear-system

I have 2 non-linear curves having (x,y)values. The x values are varying from 0 to 127 in both the curves and y values are of different magnitude for 2 curves. How can I compare these 2 non-linear curves? What are the possible comparison parameters? Please provide your inputs.

Comment: It would be better if you would post the curves with the question.

Comment: What do you need to compare them for?

Comment: I need to check for the similarity between two curves.

Comment: It is asking for at-least 10 reputations to post images that I don't have !!!

Answer (score 0):

If the two curves are $y_1 = f_1(x)$ and $y_2 = f_2(x)$, there are many ways to compute a "difference". For example:
$$
\max \left\{\left|f_1(x) - f_2(x)\right| : 0 \le x \le 127 \right\}
$$

$$
\int_0^{127} \left|f_1(x) - f_2(x)\right|dx
$$
From an abstract point of view, we are defining different "metrics" on a set of functions, and we can use any of those metrics to measure difference, or "distance". I gave you two examples of such "metrics", but there are many others.

We can't tell you which metric to use unless you tell us more about your problem.